# 5 V car accessory problem

Tags: capacitor

I have installed a car dashcam which is hardwired into the fuse box.
The camera detects the voltage to switch between driving and parking modes.
When the ignition is moved from on to engine start, the voltage to the camera drops causing it to go into park mode.

I have been advised that a capacitor between the battery line and ground may help keep the 5 V stable during the switch from on to engine start.
I need some help with the figures here.

Thanks

Comment: Did the advice come with a value for the capacitor? Where does the 5 V come from?

Comment: Can you measure or see from the specs how much current the device draws and for how long you need to hold the supply up? What kind of 5 V regulator are you using? Add the info into the question (not the comments).

Comment: I didn't get a value. The 5v comes from a small adapter that takes the 12v from the battery and steps it down to the 5v

Comment: Speak with the camera manufacturer or supplier.

Comment: The "small adapter" should have been made with the voltage drop associated with starting the car and the current draw of an attached device taken into account. Can you try a different adapter from a reputable manufacturer? (I guess that Anker has that status, but that isn't a recommendation.)

Comment: Sounds like you connected to a supply that is cut when starting the engine. Wrong one, find a supply that stays live at all times either permanent or ignition controlled.

Comment: I think the issue is that the car is a 2004 and the issue seems to be that on start up, the voltage drops to the accessories when the starter motor draws power. I can get an adapter that doesn't switch modes but I would like to keep the switching function so the camera keeps recording when parked.

Comment: dont forget to put in a diode or at least a resistor or that capacitor will just get discharged on engine start anyway.  figure out how long the start takes and size your capacitor to power the load for at least twice as long.

Comment: Mine is a 2005 and I checked for which wires do what... As I suggested in my other comment.

Comment: This voltage dip is NORMAL during engine start.  Anyone who designs a dashcam knows this.  What they are sensing is the battery system voltage *on battery* (under 12.8 volts) vs *when being charged by the running alternator* (13.4V or more).  The latter occurs when the engine is running.  Most people drive their cars with the engine running, so that is a reliable indicator to start recording.

Answer (score 1):

Check the battery voltage when starting, if it goes below 7.2V you need a new battery. If not The simple solution would be to use a SEPIC (Buck/Boost) converter. The 7.2V comes from part of the CCA (Cold cranking amps) test.